# Angular ui-grid. Error in example?

Tags: angularjs, tree, grid, angular-ui-grid

I want to use ui-grid with treeView, but in example:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView

it working wrong.

if i click on "+" icon and then click "-" icon - last row going out from grid.

How repear this, or replace to other grid with tree (hierarhical grid with several column and row selections)? Thanks!

Comment: If you have enought time, you can post an issue ticket on the ui-grid github. https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be the alignment issue that was fixed this morning, which occurs when you have filters.  The treeView appears to be working correctly today.

If you have an issue that is different than that, could you provide a bit more detail - your description is somewhat unclear on exactly what it is that is wrong.